# PDF editing software/note taking with indexing capability

Tags: windows, pdf, text-processing, document-indexing

I am a graduate student who is looking to upgrade my note taking capabilities. I am looking for a pdf editor (for windows 10) that can edit text (i.e highlight, underline, etc) but can also index specific text. So for example, I would highlight a phrase and add a comment for that phrase, that comment would appear in an index and upon clicking that comment, I would be brought to the text it is connected to. Also, it would be nice of the index/comments are searchable like the pdf.

I'd also like to be able to print my pdfs if I need to so onenote makes that difficult I believe.

While not required, I would also like to have inking capability (stylus support). So far, I am using drawboard. It's a good software, but unfortunately lacks indexing capability.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Acrobat does all of this.

- Comments are shown in a list and can be filtered. Clicking on a comment navigates to the comment location.
- Comments are searchable, but in a separate interface from document search.
- it can print the PDF with a comment summary. It's worth trying to find an older version of Acrobat , as the comment printing function used to be much better than in the current "Acrobat Pro DC 2020" release.